# What is the exact difference between v4, Seattle, Oslo and minimal master pages in sharepoint?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, master-page

I am little bit confused about the master pages in the SharePoint 2013. Please, give the exact difference between these four master pages in SharePoint.

Answer (score 3):

Differencce between the master pages are their page layouts and navigation.

**v4.master** This Is 2010 Master Page,Used for content and administration pages. Provides the interface and layout. this Team Site home page, list and library pages, and site settings page.

**Minimal master page(minimal.master)**Contains minimal SharePoint content, used for full-screen functionality or embedded applications.The home and search results pages on a Search Center, pages that host Word or Excel web applications.

[Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-SharePoint-master-pages-DC9C4388-8DCE-41B8-ABB8-EEDA2801B1A7)

**Seattle** is designed for intranet team collaboration with more features such as  social, content\site navigation and management shortcuts.

**oslo** master page is designed for published site which focus on page layout and content rendering.

[Reference](http://ravinderraopolneni-prince.blogspot.com/2014/07/seattle-vs-oslo-sharepoint-2013-master.html)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 provides several OOTB master page templates to demonstrate good master page practice to fulfil different business needs.

In general, **Seattle** is designed for intranet team collaboration with more features such as social, content\site navigation and management shortcuts.

While **Oslo** master page is designed for published site which focus on page layout and content rendering. Oslo masterpage handles anonymous users differently as well. For instance, the top ribbon is completely removed for anonymous users, while Seattle keeps it [reference 1](http://davidlozzi.com/2013/09/25/theres-more-than-meets-the-eye-differences-between-sharepoints-oslo-and-seattle-master-pages/)

More references here can explain the difference

- [reference 2](https://skdeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/differences-between-sharepoints-oslo-and-seattle-master-pages/)